# Use preg_match_all to pull all <a href links that are NOT mailto: links

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to use `preg_match_all` to scan the source of a page and pull all links that are mailto: links into one array and all links that are **not** mailto: links into another array.  Currently I'm using:

```
$searches = array('reg'=>'/href(=|=\'|=\")(?!mailto)(.+)\"/i','mailto'=>'/href(=|=\'|=\")(?=mailto)(.+)\"/i');
foreach ($searches as $key=>$search)
{
    preg_match_all($search,$source,$found[$key]);
}
```

The mailto: links search is working perfectly, but I can't find the reason why the non mailto: link search is pulling both mailto: and non-mailto: links, even with the negative look ahead assertion in place.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [**The pony, he comes**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) <-- the canonical reference for why regex parsing of [X]HTML is a bad idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A saner solution that isn't so fragile would be to use DOMDocument...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$mailLinks = $nonMailLinks = array();

$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($a as $anchor) {
   if ($anchor->hasAttribute('href')) {
      $href = trim($anchor->getAttribute('href'));
      if (substr($href, 0, 7) == 'mailto:') {
            $mailLinks[] = $href;
      } else {
            $nonMailLinks[] = $href;
      }
   }
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WBI0NZ).

Comment: Interesting, never used the DOMDocument class before.  I shall explore that option.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex looks for the shortest alternative here:

```
 (=|=\'|=\")
```

You either need to sort that `=` last, or use the more common:

```
 =[\'\"]?
```

Alternatively / or otherwise exchange the `.+?` for the more explicit/restrictive `[^\'\">]+`. So the negative assertion won't fail against '`"mailto:`' as matched by `.+`